# Does \let\a=\a do anything more than \relax?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-core

Poking around with `\show` (and `\loggingall`) in the TikZ code, I see that the definition of `\tikz@command@path` (which `\path` is `\let` to inside tikzpictures) starts with

```
\let \tikz@signal@path =\tikz@signal@path
```

Is that doing anything? The only possibilities I see are an `\afterassignment` trickery, or a *very* unlikely use of `\global`.

```
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\show\tikz@command@path
```

or, to see that this is the definition of `\path` also,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz{\show\path}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It surely blocks the premature expansion of `\pgfutil@ifnextchar` were it in an alignment; but `\relax` would do the same. There's also `\def\tikz@signal@path{\tikz@signal@path}` on line 1540 of `tikz.code.tex`. Yuk!

Comment: @egreg: Doing `\def\foo{\foo}` is actually useful. You can use it with `\futurelet` as a sentinel to process everything up to the `\foo`. As a side effect, if you get something wrong and `\foo` gets expanded, the infinite loop that results is a good way to figure out that something has gone horribly wrong.

Comment: @TH: I didn't say it's useless.

Comment: @egreg: it could be a dummy assignment to trigger a previous `\afterassignment`, but that seems like a very dirty trick.

Comment: All `\afterassignment` commands in `tikz.code.tex` are of the form `\afterassignment\xyz\let\next=`; but it's used elsewhere. Maybe. That command seems to be mainly a sentinel; like a "quark" in LaTeX3, I guess.

Comment: The only other place `\tikz@signal@path` is used is at line 41 of `tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex` in the `execute at begin cell` code for `matrix of nodes`. As far as I can tell, it is there to check whether the matrix cell contents start with a path, so that a normal matrix cell is created instead of a new node.

Comment: @Caramdir: I think that this is the answer: just above, I see `ifnextchar\let`, followed there by `ifnextchar\tikz@signal@path` in the true branch, with the comment `evil hackery to find out about start of path`.

Comment: Actually, I should have thought of this since I have used something similar (with copies of `\relax` having various names) in a package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is used to be able to tell where a path is started. The string `\tikz@signal@path` shows up again in line 41 of `tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex`.

My interpretation of the code (which might be wrong!) is that the following happens to construct a cell in a matrix with the `matrix of nodes` option:

- First the general matrix code starts setting up the cell.
- The code at `execute at begin cell` is executed. In particular, `matrix of nodes` hooks into this mechanism.
- TikZ tries to be smart about creating a node for this cell:

  - if the cell content starts with `|` then it creates a new `\node` with the things delineated by `|` as options (and anything afterwards passed as node content);
  - if the cell starts with a TikZ path then no node is created, and the cell is processed completely by the pgf code;
  - otherwise it just creates a node with the cell contents.
- PGF continues processing the cell.

The problem here is how to check whether the cell contents start with a TikZ path. This is done by checking for the presence of `\let\tikz@signal@path` at the start of the content.

So, to answer your question, the `\let \tikz@signal@path =\tikz@signal@path` does nothing (useful) when executed as part of a path, but serves as a signal to anything inspecting the code that the following code is part of a path.

Comment: Very neat piece of investigative TikZalism.

Comment: Thank you @Caramdir for the great answer. You may want to add that `\let\tikz@signal@path=\tikz@signal@path` does nothing per se, but is just there to be a recognizable "do-nothing".